# Is it secure to choose d in a RSA key pair?

Tags: rsa, public-key

An RSA key pair consists of the private key $(n,d)$ and a public key $(n,e)$ such that $de \equiv 1 \bmod{\lambda(n)} $.

Usually one chooses a small $e$ and computes $d$ by inverting it modulo $\lambda(n)$. This makes things computationally easy for the user of the public key, but makes it expensive to use the private key because $d$ is large (typically only a few bits shorter than $n$).

If one wants to shift computational cost from the private to the public side of the cryptosystem, would it be secure to select $d$ as, say, a random 128-bit number coprime to $\lambda(n)$ and then compute $e$ as its inverse instead of the usual way around?

Comment: If you can't use a different algorithm with faster signing/decryption, you could use multi-prime RSA and CRT. It's not a big speedup, but still nice if performance is really important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selecting a small $d$ is known to be insecure.

Wiener has shown in 1990 that if $\log d \leq \frac14 \log N$, the private exponent $d$ can be reconstructed from the public key $(N,e)$.

If you're interested in making the private computational cost cheaper, then I would suggest that RSA is not the best solution; I would recommend you start looking at Elliptic Curve based solutions.